# Fatal Error with Joomfish trying to translate content

Tags: joomla, joomfish

I'm updating a joomla 1.5 webpage to a joomla 2.5.

**The Problem:**

An error screen comes up saying:

```
Fatal error: Call to protected method JFormField::getName() from context 'TranslateParams_xml' in /var/www/vhosts/1286.linux3.testsider.dk/httpdocs/jupgrade/libraries/joomfish/translateparams/xml.php on line 114
```

I've looked at line 114 in the xml.php but I can't seem to find any errors in it. That's when i thought to myself maybe this problem is caused due to me working in a subfolder og det online [webpage](http://www.trademarktex.com/jupgrade/).

Is it because of the subfolder? A damaged file? Or something else?

Here's the xml.php

```
    foreach ($fieldset as $field) {
            $freefield = JFFormField::getInstance($field);
            //if($freefield->type == 'Spacer') continue;

            $freefieldname              = $freefield->get('fieldname');

            $freefield->set('fieldname',$freefieldname.'_orig' );
Line 114    $freefield->set('name', $freefield->getName($freefieldname.'_orig'));
            $freefield->set('label', 'Original '.$freefield->get('label'));
```

Maybe it's easier to start from scratch with the content in the Joomfish for Joomla 2.5?

Comment: Is this file from the 2.5 version of joomfish?

Comment: - Riccardo, Yes it is.. But the previous translations aren't .

Comment: Look here, you might need a jupgrade plugin to handle it: http://www.joomfish.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=12155

Answer (score -1):

The resolution of this very problem has been the creation of lacking functions

`getName()` in file `libraries/joomfish/form/jfformfield.php`

and then create second function

`addNode()` in file   `libraries/joomfish/form/jfform.php`